# "isWindows is not defined" error when using create-nuxt-app v3.6.0

Tags: frameworks, nuxt.js

I'm about to learn Nuxt JS and start to install it with this command:
`npx create-nuxt-app@3.6.0 nuxt-crud`

But I get this error:

[image]

I've tried to search the solution, but unfortunately i still not found it yet.
Anyone knows what happen with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just use `npx create-nuxt-app my-cool-project` and it works well.

Meanwhile, I can totally reproduce the same error as you here.

Looking at the [latest releases](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/releases), there is a `3.7.0` version available.
I've tried `npx create-nuxt-app@3.7 nuxt-crud` and it's working great so far.